# Rules and regulations of property distribution in case of religious changing

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, conversion, inheritance

If someone changed his/her religious what will be the criteria of distribution of inheritance property?? Is it will be changed according to previous religious or current religious??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convert to Islam:**

He\She will receive inheritance from Muslim relations but will not receive inheritance from non-Muslim relations.

On his\her death, Muslim heirs will receive the estate, any non-Muslim relatives will not receive anything.

**Who leave Islam:**

He\She will not receive inheritance from any one.

On his\her death, following opinions regarding distribution of estate:

- It will all be confiscated into Bayt-ul-Maal
- It will all be distributed among any Muslim heirs.
- The portion earned while they were Muslims will be distributed to the Muslim heirs, anything earned during apostasy will be confiscated.

For detail see

https://archive.org/stream/MosouaFiqhiyah-urdu-01-45/Mosoua-Fiqhiyah-03#page/n67/mode/2up
https://archive.org/stream/MosouaFiqhiyah-urdu-01-45/Mosoua-Fiqhiyah-22#page/n239/mode/2up